# static DataGrid column width in C# in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I tried doing

```
for (int x = 0; x < gridQuestion.Columns.Count; x++)
{
    gridQuestion.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width = 50;
}
```

but the columns still go across the page (not wrapping).

It should wrap if I get it right yes?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Wrap property of the ItemStyle (though it *should* be true by default):

```
for (int x = 0; x < gridQuestion.Columns.Count; x++)
{
    gridQuestion.Columns[x].HeaderStyle.Width = 50;
    gridQuestion.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width = 50;
    gridQuestion.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Wrap = true;
}
```

Comment: i repopulated my DB but now everything is warpped to the size of my header instead of the specified width

Comment: by header i mean the column name in my DB

Comment: @user904406 - You probably need to set the header width to match the width of your column as well.  See my edit.